# The recipient device is not registered with FCM

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The page I'm sending with fcm is having internal error 500

I don't want the page to be errored out with 500

```
$interestDetails = [$user->tokenid, $user->token];
$expo = \ExponentPhpSDK\Expo::normalSetup();
$expo->subscribe($interestDetails[0], $interestDetails[1]);
$a = $notification = ['title'=>'xxx','body' => 'yyyy'];
$a = $expo->notify($interestDetails[0], $notification);
```

Comment: What errors do you see if you take a look at the server logs?

Comment: The registration token you are trying to send a notification to is registered to another Firebase project. Please make sure that the app that generated the token and your FCM Key/Service Account belong to the same Firebase project.

Comment: information is correct. Some users do not give error some users do not give error